# How to check if one field is defined among a collection of entities?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am working on symfony2 and twig.

Here is my problem :

My Employees can have Vehicles. Some vehicles can have fine.For example.

I want to check if among the vehicles of my employee one has a dateFine.
If one vehicle has a dateFine, I want to diplay a general alert : "Warning : One of your vehicles has a fine."

In my employee.html.twig view, I would write something like that :

```
    {% for vehicle in employee.vehicles %}
        {% if vehicle.dateFine is defined %}
           <div> Warning : one of your vehicle has a fine. </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

**problem** :of course, with that code, if 2 vehicles have a dateFine, I would have 2 alerts, and I want to have only one. So I only need to check if a dateFine is defined among all of my employee's vehicles, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is some kind of logic you may want to reuse later or at least have control over in your object, I would move the logic into your model. The best way to do this is adding a hasFine to your employee object:

```
class Employee {
    public function hasFine() {
        foreach($this->vehicles AS $vehicle) {
            if($vehicle->getDateFine() != null) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

In your template you can use this function:

```
{% if employee.hasFine %}
    <div> Warning : one of your vehicle has a fine. </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best approach may be to move this logic to the employee class. Create a method called `hasVehicleDateFine()` in Employee and then do the looping and logic there.